# how apply scroll-sneak to my site

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, pageload

Hello I am currently look for solutions for keeping my scroll position on page load and I found this page ( http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/ ). Its javascript to keep scroll bar location on page load, but I just cant seem to get it working after looking through the page source and trying different things for a while (im not very experienced with JS) Could someone check this out and see if they can break it down a bit more for me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this git page comments the script a bit more.https://gist.github.com/ohaal/6882141 I'll give you an update when I have applied this to my own site. Probably I can give you a better explanation. What first comes in mind is that you need to set a ID by the latest script explained in the git page above.

```
// Example of applying sneak to a link:
/*
(function() {
    var sneaky = new ScrollSneak(location.hostname);
    document.getElementById('sneakytest').onclick =    sneaky.sneak;
})();
 */
```